# FullCalendar displays "more" when not needed

Tags: fullcalendar

My calendar can show only 2 lines in a day cell (month view). The third event of the same day overflows underneath. So I used the property eventLimit, but :

- if I set it to true, the cells with 2 events display only "more" (though it's not needed, the 2 events could stand there). None of the events are displayed.
- if I set it to 2, the second event is replaced with "more". It is the behavior I would expect when there are 3 events or more. For 2 events, it's a nonsense.
- if I set it to 3, when there are 3 events, all the 3 are displayed, though that's when a "more" would be expected.

The "more" should replace the second event only when there are more than 2 events. Is it possible to get this ?

Comment: This behaviour sounds odd, and is not obvious from the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimit), so perhaps you could consider raising a [bug report](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) as it doesn't appear to behave in the documented way.

Comment: Can you please share fullcalendar code. There are times when another property may override or some other property in View-Specific Options may work for you: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options

Comment: Please also confirm the version used?

Answer (score 0):

Found !

This behaviour was due to events on 2 consecutive days : 2 events the 25/01, during 2 days, and one more event the 26. That explains why the events on the 25 could not expand on the 26.

Thanks for your help.